# How to stop for loop execution untill DWR method execution completion which is inside the for loop

Tags: javascript, dwr

Please see this code:

```
for(var k=0;k<pods.length;k++){
        var currentQueryList = new Array();
        currentQueryList[0]=pods[k].queryname;
        console.log("Hello :"+i);
        queryBuilderDWRService.getDataForAllPods(currentQueryList, {callback:function(map){
            podsDataMap = map;
            console.log("Hello"+k+":");
            var pod = pods[k];
            displayPod(k, pod, false);
        }});
    }
```

In this code, the for loop is completing before the call to `queryBuilderDWRService.getDataForAllPods()` returns actual data, which I'm using to get data from a database.

It I try `console.log("Hello"+i);` it is printing `Hello :1, Hello :2, Hello :3, Helllo :4,` up to array length with no data from DB, meaning that the for loop is completing its execution before than `queryBuilderDWRService.getDataForAllPods()` returns.

What I need is that, once control is entering in the for loop, it has to complete the execution of queryBuilderDWRService.getDataForAllPods() and only then the next iteration can follow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to this depends on how this QueryBuilderDWRService is written.  Since getDataForAllPods is executing asynchronously then it probably has a way of signaling that it is complete via a callback, event firing, etc.

Comment: @Egg I expect that would be the callback function in the OP's code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "asynchronous pseudo-recursion" instead of a `for` loop, with the general pattern that I use being:

```
var pods = [ ... ];

(function loop() {
    if (pods.length) {
        var pod = pods.shift();   // take (and remove) first element

        // do something with "pod"
        ...

        // recurse - put this inside a finish callback if "do something" is async
        loop();
     }
})();   // closing braces start invocation immediately
```

where in your case, the call to `loop` should be the last thing inside your callback function.

---

NB: This pattern can also be used to avoid the "browser not responding" error seen with longer running non-async operations by replacing the call to `loop()` with `setTimeout(loop, 0)`.

This use of `setTimeout` turns a synchronous recursive function into an asynchronous pseudo-recursive one, in the process avoiding the possibility of any stack overflow errors.

The only downside is the 4ms minimum delay between iterations.

Comment: Thanks for replying Alnitak.. Sorry im unable to do the code changes according to what you are saying..Could you please add me full code

Comment: no, that wouldn't teach you anything.  You need to put `var currentQueryList= [ pod.queryname ]; after the `shift` line, and put `loop()` in the last line of your callback .  You will no longer have the variable `k` available, so just create it outside the `loop` and increment it in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

From the way you have it setup, the call you are making is likely async and therefore the loop will complete execution before the callback to the function you have defined. So it seems you want to build up your currentQueryList array and then make a single call to getDataForAllPods and then, in the callback, finish up the display.  What is it that is returned in the map?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a self executing function, called a closure.

```
var currentQueryList = [];
for(var i=0,l=pods.length; i<l; i++){
  (function(i){
    currentQueryList[0]=pods[i].queryname;
    console.log('Hello :'+i);
    queryBuilderDWRService.getDataForAllPods(currentQueryList, {callback:function(map){
      podsDataMap = map;
      console.log('Hello'+i+':');
      var pod = pods[i];
      displayPod(i, pod, false);
    }});
  })(i);
}
```

The problem is, when you call the event, the loop has already run through. Since `i` is scoped within your loop, when the event fires, it looks for the value of `i`, which is `pods.length-1`, since you have used `<`. You need the scope of your increment to be stored into separate memory spaces, which will be accessed when the event fires.

Note that you have made podsDataMap a global variable, and I changed your code slightly.

Comment: this will fix the variable binding problem, but each query will still run in parallel rather than in series.